# Json Array not properly generated in jsp

Tags: json, jsp

I have written `jsp` code for generating json .But its not generating exact `JsonArray`. Its like

```
[{"item":"747"},,{"item":"1617"},]
```

instead of

```
[{"item":"747"},{"item":"1617"}].
```

below is the code

```
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    obj.put("item", "747");
    ja.put(obj);
    obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("item", "1617");
    ja.put(obj);
    out.println(ja);
```

Comment: I tried your code, and works fine. what gson are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I have tested your code by using [json-simple-1.1.1.jar](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/detail?name=json-simple-1.1.1.jar&can=2&q=), worked fine there is no extra `,` came in output. while testing your code eclipse given one error message like put() method is undefined for the type `JSONArray`, so i replaced put with add like:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
obj.put("item", "747");
ja.add(obj);
obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("item", "1617");
ja.add(obj);
out.println(ja);
```

Also see [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)